# Yii2 construct a query with union and limit

Tags: php, sql, yii2, query-builder

I need to construct an SQL query containing two queries combined by `UNION` and limit a number of rows returned.

```
    $query = $queryOne
        ->union($queryTwo)
        ->limit($this->limit)
    ;
```

The problem is that the `LIMIT` clause is enclosed in parentheses with the first query. As a result of this the second query has no `LIMIT` clause.

I need to specify the `LIMIT` clause for the whole query not for a subquery.

Comment: I think that you have two solutions; 1) if sql is simple, write sql directly; 2) if sql is complex, create a view from sql and then call it from Yii;

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli thanks for assistance. Already found a solution without hacking raw SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a third query to solve the problem somewhat elegantly:

```
    $query = (new Query)
        ->select('*')
        ->from([
            $queryOne->union($queryTwo),
        ])
        ->offset($offset)
        ->limit($limit)
    ;
```

[Related](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7992).